How can I use preserve the Parent Component State in the Child Component when calling a function?
I am trying to log the correct parent component state for process.groundLeases, however when I call the parent function called onRemoveGroundLease it logs the original unmodified state. I did read something about state being isolated between components based on their place in the UI tree. However I am passing the state from the child to the parent, so I'm not sure how to fix this. How can I make sure the state is the one used in the parent?
Parent Component
const CollateralChecks : React.FC = () => {
  const [processes, setProcesses] = React.useState<ICollateralCheckProcess[]>([]);
  const [process, setProcess] = React.useState<ICollateralCheckProcess>(null);



const getProcesses = (procId?: number) => {
    console.log(process.groundLeases);
    if (selectedPropertyId) {
      onCommonGet({
        url: collateralCheckUrl.getProcess(selectedPropertyId),
        successCallback: (data: ICollateralCheckProcess[]) => {
          setProcesses(data);
          if (procId && procId !== 0) {
            const proc = data.find((d) => d.collateralCheckProcessId === procId);
            if (proc) {
              console.log(data);
              setProcess({
                ...proc,
              groundLeases: proc.groundLeases
              });
            }
          }
        }
      }, ServiceEnum.COLLATERAL_API);
    } else {
      setProcesses([]);
    }
  };

     const onRemoveGroundLease = (groundLease: ICloserGroundLease) => {
    console.log(process.groundLeases);**<--- Here it logs a different state**
    const groundLeaseIds = process.groundLeases?.map((gl) => gl.arkGroundLeaseId);
    if (groundLeaseIds) {
      const index = groundLeaseIds.indexOf(groundLease.arkGroundLeaseId);
      if (index > -1) {
        groundLeaseIds.splice(index, 1)
      }

      const payload: IProcessGroundLeaseSave = {
        processId: process.collateralCheckProcessId,
        groundLeaseIds
      };
      onCommonPut({
        url: collateralCheckUrl.associateGroundLeases(),
        payload,
        successCallback: () => {
          getProcesses(process.collateralCheckProcessId);
          onCancelProcessEdit();
        }
      }, ServiceEnum.COLLATERAL_API);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <CollateralCheckForm
        onRemoveGroundLease={onRemoveGroundLease}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default CollateralChecks;

Child Component
  export interface ICollateralCheckFormProps {
  process: ICollateralCheckProcess;
  onRemoveGroundLease: (groundLease: ICloserGroundLease) => void;
}

const CollateralCheckForm: React.FC<ICollateralCheckFormProps> = ({
  process,
  onRemoveGroundLease
}) => {

           <BaseGrid
                  data={process.groundLeases || []} **<-- data in grid**
                  onGridReady={handleGridReady}
                  fields={processGroundLeaseFields}
                  frameworkComponents={{
                    renderDeleteAction: buildDeleteActionCell({
                      onDelete: onRemoveGroundLease **<--Parent function called**
                    }),
                  }}
                />
};

export default CollateralCheckForm;


I'm pretty sure you're running into the stale closure problem here (BaseGrid or buildDeleteActionCell maybe?). Nothing to do with the isolation between the components.

Did you mean to pass the process as a prop to <CollateralCheckForm>?

What do you mean by "original unmodified state", where in your code are you modifying the state?

Yes, I am passing process as a prop to . The state is modified in the backend. I have edited to show somewhat of that.

"I am passing process as a prop to " - then please [edit] your code to show that

"The state is modified in the backend" - not sure what you mean. Doing things in the backend doesn't change in anything in the frontend? How are you running your react code?

I have added clearer code with the functions displayed.
